# How to put Font Awesome icon in an input tag using pure css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to put the font awesome icon in input tag by using only CSS. If I try to give margin or padding, font awesome icon is trying to move input tag also. Please help how to achieve this by only using CSS. And this is a react project

This is my code

`````
import React from 'react';
import './Home.css';

function Home() {
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div className='Home'>
                        <span><i className="fas fa-search iconstyle"></i></span>
                        <input type='text' placeholder='Search'>
                        </input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
````

This is css
````
.iconstyle {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

```

If I am not clear with my doubt, please put a comment
`````

Comment: can you also provide your css

Comment: I shared CSS as well in my question, please check it one @Markipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant see what you've tried so far, but this is basically what you wanted. Just basing it in your description.

```
.Home{ 
  position: relative; 
}
.Home span{ 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 10px; /* any position you want to set, (right, left, top, bottom) */
}
```